Oracle Refresh materialized views without base table
What happens when we try to refresh a materialized view in Oracle whose base table doesn't exist or is dropped accidentally after sometime.
Can we refresh it using any of the methods - fast, force or complete?
I tried to search the solution for in Google but couldn't find it.

What do you mean by "base table" - the materialized segment holding the MV results? Or one of the tables the MV view SQL queries?

The table used in MV view SQL query.

A query can't run if it refers to objects that don't exist. That means your MV will not be able to refresh. There is no solution to your problem other than recreating the missing table or changing your query to refer to a different table that exists.

the MV become invalid
select * from dba_mviews where mview_name='';

My question is what happens when we try to refresh such a MV using fast, force or complete method

you will get and ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
